# how to change Progressbar value based on password requirements in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I achieve that a Progressbar shows the strength of password like:

[image: desired output screenshot]

---

I tried to make a value called paswordStrength and I put it in onchanged event in textformfield but it didn't work

[image: my tried code snapshot]

Comment: how you are controlling progress bar, share piece of code here

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: completely recalculate your password strength on every on change, don't increment or decrement it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code for `3 conditions 8 characters, smallcase, and uppercase`

you can try this out and you can add more conditions.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  double strength = 0.0;
  bool eightCharacters = false;
  bool smallCase = false;
  bool uppercase = false;
  bool specialCharacter = false;
  bool numeric = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children:[
        TextFormField(
          onChanged: (value){
            setState((){
              //empty
              if(value.isEmpty){
                strength = 0;
                eightCharacters =false;
                smallCase = false;
                uppercase = false;
              }
              
              // 8 characters
              if(value.length >= 8){
                if(eightCharacters == false){
                eightCharacters = true;
                strength +=0.2;
                }
              }
              else{
               if(eightCharacters){
                 strength-=0.2;
                 eightCharacters = false;
               }
              }
              
              // smallCase
              if(RegExp(r"[a-z]").hasMatch(value)){
                if(!smallCase){
                  strength += 0.2;
                  smallCase = true;
                }
              }
              else{
                if(smallCase){
                  strength -= 0.2;
                  smallCase = false;
                  
                }
              }
              
              //uppercase
              if(RegExp(r"[A-Z]").hasMatch(value)){
                if(!uppercase){
                  strength += 0.2;
                  uppercase = true;
                }
              }
              else{
                if(uppercase){
                  strength -= 0.2;
                  uppercase = false;
                }
              }
            
            });
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border:OutlineInputBorder())
        ),
        const SizedBox(
        height: 100),
        LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: strength,minHeight: 20),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

refer this code and you will be able to achieve your goal.

It looks like this,

[image: achieved output from above code]